# Break Loop in hasnext on newline

Tags: java

I have a input like this:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI

XYZ
MNO
QRZ
```

I want to read this via hasnext, but want to store them in two separate ArrayList. How can I do that? Like I want to break out of loop at `\n` character, again want to continue afterward. Please help me out. Thanks

My code:

```
String s;
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
while (fr.hasNext()){
    s = fr.next();
    if(s.isEmpty()) break;
    list1.add(s);
}

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
while (fr.hasNext()){
    s = fr.next();
    list2.add(s);
}

System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Output:

```
[ABC, DEF, GHI, XYZ, MNO, QRZ]
[]
```

But I want:

```
[ABC, DEF, GHI]
[XYZ, MNO, QRZ]
```

Comment: Use two separate loops to populate the lists individually. Check if the entered string is empty in the first loop to see when to break.

Comment: I was doing so, but not working. Could you please provide me the code? @AndyTurner

Comment: How about you show your attempt, so we can help you understand why it didn't work. I'd rather help you understand than provide you with code you don't understand.

Comment: while (fr.hasNextLine()){
            s = fr.next();
            if(s.isEmpty()) break;
            lines.add(s);
        }

I was doing this. If string is empty then break, and then in second loop, I was doing same to read after the break. @AndyTurner

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add code for a [mcve].

Comment: Could you please see now @AndyTurner

Comment: I said you need a second loop. You said you had tried that, but your code doesn't have a second loop. Please include your second loop. Also, please say what your code does, and how that differs from what you need.

Comment: Btw, a call to `fr.hasNextLine()` should be paired with a call to `fr.nextLine()`, not `fr.next()`.

Comment: Hi @AndyTurner, would you please see now the question? And Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: The Scanner isn't reading the newline - that would be an empty token. Read the Javadoc of Scanner to see what it has to say about empty tokens.

Comment: We can easily do it using Spliterator. You will get a `List<String>` every time for 3 lines. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Stream` for that job:

```
String input = "ABC\n" + "DEF\n" + "GHI\n" + "\n" + "XYZ\n" + "MNO\n" + "QRZ";

List<List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(input.split("\n\n"))
            .map(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\n")).collect(Collectors.toList())).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
[[ABC, DEF, GHI], [XYZ, MNO, QRZ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have currently is that `Scanner`, by default, doesn't read empty tokens in its `next()` method, so it simply doesn't "see" the newline.

The easiest fix for this (assuming your tokens appear on separate lines, ofc) is not to use `hasNext()/next()`, but instead to use:

```
while (fr.hasNextLine()){
    s = fr.nextLine();
// ...
```

`nextLine()` can read empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using BufferedReader class. Thanks to everyone for contributing.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s;
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
String str = "";
while ((s = br.readLine())!=null){
    if(s.isEmpty()) break;
    list1.add(s);
}

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
while ((s = br.readLine())!=null){
    if(s.isEmpty()) break;
    list2.add(s);
}


System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Test.java

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            // get Spliterator from stream of lines
            Spliterator<String> linesSpliterator = lines.spliterator();
            // pass linesSpliterator to custom spliterator
            // TextSpliterator will generate new spliterator which will give List of 3 lines
            // from linesSpliterator
            Spliterator<List<String>> textSpliterator = new TextSpliterator(linesSpliterator);

            // create stream out of new Spliterator generator by TextSpliterator
            Stream<List<String>> textStream = StreamSupport.stream(textSpliterator, false);

            textStream.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On `textStream`, you can perform further operations.

Spliterator implementation:

TextSpliterator.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class TextSpliterator implements Spliterator<List<String>> {
    private final Spliterator<String> lineSpliterator;
    private String firstLine;
    private String secondLine;
    private String thirdLine;

    public TextSpliterator(Spliterator<String> lineSpliterator) {
        this.lineSpliterator = lineSpliterator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<String>> action) {
        if (this.lineSpliterator.tryAdvance(line -> this.firstLine = line)
                && this.lineSpliterator.tryAdvance(line -> this.secondLine = line)
                && this.lineSpliterator.tryAdvance(line -> this.thirdLine = line)) {
            // skip empty line
            this.lineSpliterator.tryAdvance(System.out::print);
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(firstLine, secondLine, thirdLine);
            action.accept(list);
            return true;
        } else {
            // stop when no next 3 lines found
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<List<String>> trySplit() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return lineSpliterator.estimateSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return lineSpliterator.characteristics();
    }
}
```

file.txt

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR

BBC
ABC
CCN

AAJ
TAK
WBC

AAA
BBB
CCC
```

textStream forEach generated Output:

```
[ABC, XYZ, PQR]
[BBC, ABC, CCN]
[AAJ, TAK, WBC]
[AAA, BBB, CCC]
```